# How can I rename a directory with name made of non-printable characters only

Tags: directory, solaris

On SunOS I have directories with names containing only non-printable characters. The command

```
ls -ldb *
```

returns the following (some spaces deleted)

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 user1 group1 3 Feb 4 18:10 \0122011\0122016\0122016\0122016\0122011\0122011\0122011\0122011\0122011\0122011\0122016\0122011\0122012/
drwxr-xr-x 3 user1 group1 3 Feb 4 11:03 \0122016\0122016/
```

How can I rename these directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar text as `ls -ldb *` could be produced by (ksh, bash, zsh) `$'...'`, as this:

```
echo $'\0122016\0122016'
```

Which is just a bunch of new-lines (Oct 012, Hex 0x0A) and years.

If limited on the shell you could use, then use printf :

```
printf '\0122016\0122016'
```

Note that the above code does not include the last `/`. Which in fact is not needed to give the name of the directory to the kernel.

So, to erase, use:

```
rmdir "$(printf '\0122016\0122016')"
```

To rename use:

```
mv "$(printf '\0122016\0122016')" newname
```

The other file will need this:

```
mv "$(printf '\0122011\0122016\0122016\0122016\0122011\0122011\0122011\0122011\0122011\0122011\0122016\0122011\0122012')" newname
```

Or, if there are **not** other files with a similar name, a shorter string:

```
mv "$(printf '\0122011\0122016\0122016\0122016')"* newname
```

Comment: Your answer is good :D

Comment: Please review the edits :D

Comment: Ok, I think its perfect :D

Answer (score 1):

**C/C++ code**

```
#include<cstdio>

int main(){
 rename(Old,New);
}
```

**Compile**

Reeplace `Old` and `New` using quotes `\"` and double back slash `\\`

`g++ -O3 -o bin file.cpp -D Old=\"\\0122016\\0122016/\" -D New=\"new\"`

**Run**

`./bin`

Answer (score 1):

Untested pseudocode:

```
i=1
for d in *
do
  echo "$d"
  echo Enter Y to rename the above directory:
  read answer
  if [ $answer = "Y" ]
  then
    mv "$d" tempdir${i}
    i=$((i+1))
  fi
done
```